# mq notify returns -1, not notifying when it should

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, signals, message-queue

I am having problem with my mq_notify not notifying me when there is something to read in the message queue.

Here is my code:

```
void * mqClient(void * arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    int errnum;
    int retval;

    char thread_id[30];
    char thread_id2[30] = "/";

    sprintf(thread_id, "%d", pthread_self());

    strcat(thread_id2, thread_id);

    printf("\nEnter planet name: ");
    scanf("%s", planet.name);

    printf("\nEnter planet X-position: ");
    scanf("%lf", &planet.sx);

    printf("\nEnter planet Y-position: ");
    scanf("%lf", &planet.sy);

    printf("\nEnter planet X-velocity: ");
    scanf("%lf", &planet.vx);

    printf("\nEnter planet Y-velocity: ");
    scanf("%lf", &planet.vy);

    printf("\nEnter planet mass: ");
    scanf("%lf", &planet.mass);

    printf("\nEnter planet life time: ");
    scanf("%d", &planet.life);

    strcpy(planet.pid, thread_id2);

    mqd_t mq_on_server;
    usleep(1000);

    int response = MQconnect(&mq_on_server, "/servermq");

    if(response == 0)
        printf("Something went wrong with MQconnect\n");
    else
        MQwrite (mq_on_server, &planet);

    strcat(thread_id2, thread_id);

    //Create a messagequeue responsible for sending server-client specific messages

     int response2 = MQcreate(&clientMQ, planet.pid);

     if(response2 != 1)
         printf("\nNO success in creating a message queue between client and server!");
     else
     {
         printf("\nSUCCESS in creating a message queue (%s) between client and server!\n", planet.pid);
     }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------");

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sev.sigev_notify_function = sigNotifier;
    sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &response2;

    retval = mq_notify(response2, &sev);

    printf("\n%d", retval);

    if(retval < 0)
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("Error printed by perror");
        fprintf(stderr,"Notification failed: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    /*int c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);*/

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}
```

and the sigNotifier:

```
static void sigNotifier(union sigval sv)
{

        printf("Notification!");

        char msg[1000];

        MQread(clientMQ, msg);

        printf("\nMessage received from server: %s", msg);
}
```

Error values:

```
Value of errno: 9
Error printed by perror: Bad file descriptor
Notification failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I am always getting the return value -1 from mq_notify. Am I missing something in my code?

There is no problem with the server writing to the message queue. I have checked that the client can read from the message queue and it can but I want it to only read from the message queue when there is something to read. I had the problem that the program got stuck on MQread till there is something to read but I dont want that behaviour, therefore I thought that a signal handler could solve the problem.

Comment: "on error, -1 is returned, with errno set to indicate the error." So what error code is set in errno?

Comment: @user253751 It says bad file descriptor

Comment: so according to the documentation, what does that mean? (look at "ERRORS" -https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mq_notify.2.html - and guess which code is "bad file descriptor")

Comment: @user253751 Yes I did manage to find the fault. According to the documentation this is the fault:  The message queue descriptor specified in mqdes is invalid. That means response2 as argument is invalid. Instead I changed it to clientMQ as it is my mqd_t mqdes and it worked. Thank you very much for your tips.